# how to ignore a column in a file delimited with | while using a import command to replace data from a db2 table

Tags: linux, shell, import, db2, db2-luw

For eg:
Data in the file is as below:

```
12|Jake|456|Doctor|1996|pisces
```

Table:

```
ID-Name-Job-BirthYear-Sign
```

So the command that I'am using:

```
db2 "Load CLIENT FROM ABC.FILE of DEL MODIFIED BY coldel0x7x keepblanks REPLACE INTO tablename(ID,Name,Job,BirthYear,sign) nonrecoverable"
```

So By using this command 456 is getting inserted into job column and doctor in Birthyear column and pieces is missing. So how can I ignore or remove 3rd column from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Db2 [LOAD command syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html) and the **METHOD** clause (under **MODIFIED BY**). The METHOD has the suboptions L, N, and P. P is to specify the position of columns to consider in the input file. You would say something like

```
   OF DEL MODIFIED BY coldel0x7x keepblanks METHOD P(1,2,4,5,6)
```

Comment: how to concatenate  ID and job i.e "12Doctor" and insert into table from File. Is there any command

Comment: That's actually a different question. Usually you would just use "id || job".